# Passing arguments to r script for a parametric plot

Tags: r, plot, parameters

I want to make an R script to produce a simple scatter plot, passing the columns to plot as a parameter.

This is what I'm doing now:

```
ds <- read.csv("filename", sep=";")
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
x <- args[1]
y <- args[2]
output <- args[3]

png(output)
plot(ds$x, ds$y)
dev.off()
```

Then I launch the script this way:
`Rscript myscript.R arg1 arg2 output.png`,
but I get the execution halted because it can't fetch any data.

If I use the correct column name in the plot function (having read the column header **offline**), it works well of course.

If I ask for `typeof(ds$x)` I get NULL, so the problem seems to be the `args` are not of the correct type; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ds$y` and `ds$x` will not work in this form because x and y are characters.

If you try on your console:

```
x <- 'arg1'
> ds$x
NULL
```

You will see it will not work and will return NULL.

Therefore try this:

```
ds <- read.csv("filename", sep=";")
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
x <- args[1]
y <- args[2]
output <- args[3]

png(output)
plot(ds[,x], ds[,y])
dev.off()
```

Comment: @atiretoo That's ok. Your solution is not wrong anyway, it's just that it is simpler to use `[` IMO.

Comment: It works, and moreover, if I use this syntax, I can even pass the column number to x and y, and casting x and y to numeric:
`x <- as.numeric(args[1])`
it keeps working nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, the problem is with the type of x and y. Add

```
cat(class(x),"\n")
```

to your script and you see that the type of x is character. So change the call to plot to

```
plot(get(x,ds),get(y,ds))
```

and it works.

Comment: Great @atiretoo, it works indeed. What class should `x` and `y` have to be read without the use of `get`?

Comment: args[] will always have characters in it. As you saw above you have to use `as.numeric()` to get numbers to use. the [ operator is much better than get() in this case.